# Django mod_wsgi request takes 6 secs

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

In short, my question is my requests take a long time and I am unable to find out why. I don't know of anything else I can do to figure out why its taking so long. What are some other techniques I may have overlooked to help my shorten the request time?

This whole scenario has left me scratching my head for quite a long time now. I have created a test server as a virtual box and loaded with vagrant on the server. Whenever I try to visit the Apache/Django website from the virtualbox's host machine though the requests take on average 6 seconds. I read that mod_wsgi was supposed to take time to load up the first time, however it still take around 6 seconds to load even on subsequent visits.

This is the output from Django toolbar

```
Resource    Value
User CPU time   183.972 msec
System CPU time     606.908 msec
Total CPU time  790.880 msec
Elapsed time    5720.771 msec
Context switches    12800 voluntary, 21 involuntary
```

As you can see, the elapsed time is really high whereas the total CPU time is right around a minute. I am a little worried about the high number of `Context switches` though. Regardless I next tried to profile Apache with the following command

```
$ ab -n 400 http://127.0.0.1:8080/scheduling/instruments
...
Time taken for tests:   5.389 seconds
Complete requests:      400
...
Time per request:       13.473 [ms] (mean)
```

This doesn't make any sense to me since it managed to complete 400 requests in the time it takes my browser to complete one. When I make the same exact request in my browser it took the usual 6 seconds. My only last thought is that the request must be somehow taking 5 seconds for mod_wsgi to boot django and process the request from there. Below is the relevant section in my `httpd.conf` file and my `django.wsgi` file used to serve the application

```
# Use apache to serve the static media files
AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/media/(.*) /var/www/apps/$1/media/$2

<DirectoryMatch ^/var/www/apps/([^/]+)/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>

WSGIDaemonProcess django_apps user=apache group=root
WSGIProcessGroup django_apps
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/([^/]+) /var/www/apps/$1/django.wsgi
```

and the django.wsgi apache loads

```
import os
import sys

path = '/var/www/apps'
path2 = '/var/www/apps/scheduling'
path3 = '/var/www/apps/scheduling/debug_toolbar'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
if path2 not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path2)
if path3 not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path3)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'scheduling.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

import scheduling.monitor
scheduling.monitor.start(interval=1.0)
```

the scheduling.monitor is copied verbatim from this website [Reloading Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Monitoring_For_Code_Changes)

If it helps any, the server is a VirtualBox hosted on my local Mac Lion with all the port forwarding properly setup. The server is Centos 6 with the default installed Apache 2.2 and Django 1.3.1

---

Edit: It turns out the problem was that it was on a VM. Because the VM was configured to use my local machine as the DNS, DNS lookups could take upwards of 5 seconds from inside the machine. That meant any time the machine went to connect to another server (aka looking up our SQL server), it would freeze, coincidentally between when mod_wsgi gets the request and my python views receive the request. Changing the values in `/etc/resolv.conf` to our local DNS fixed the problem.

Comment: Set the CustomLog directive of Apache to log response time in the access log. That will tell you whether issue is outside of inside of Apache. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog Also set LogLevel to info so that mod_wsgi logs details of process restarts to see whether you are doing something which causes a new process to be created for every request.

Comment: Thanks for the advice so far! So I made another log that used %D and %T and for any static media request Apache fills that in milliseconds, but once again any django page takes a minimum of 5 seconds even if its as trivial as outputing a text filled page. With log level on info I see these lines when I first visit but not on subsequent visits unless I update the code `Create interpreter` `mod_wsgi (pid=3976, process='...', application='...',)` and then `Starting change monitor` I don not see it adding these line on any requests except the first one.

Comment: I'm still not sure why any django request takes over 5 seconds. I stopped any other large processes taking up RAM or CPU and the vm is now running around 50% memory and 5% CPU on standby. Regardless of the increase in memory though, the requests still take 5 seconds. Is there any other effective ways to profile this app?

Comment: Besides suggesting that you use a variant of http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Tracking_Request_and_Response which records time stamps and so work out whether issue is within Django application or not, can only suggest you perhaps try New Relic which does that that and a lot more.

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the advice and help. It turns out that the VM was configured to use my local machine as a DNS which would make any DNS lookups take 5 seconds or so. In order to solve this, I made `/etc/resolv.conf` point straight to our workplace's local DNS and to prevent the system from overwriting it I called `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` and bam! It now takes a reasonable amount of time per request.